# Space in String argument is not parsed by args4j

Tags: java, string, command-line-arguments, args4j

I'm trying to pass a text/String parameter to my java tool from Jenkins which is a String containing all sorts of characters.

When the args4j option parses the flag then it only considers the first word and as soon as it hits the second word(after space) it starts throwing an exception.

here's a snippet

```
@Option(name = "-data_string", usage = "Data")
 private String dataString;
```

When I pass argument as -data_string="This is a test" then I get Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)Caused by: org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: "-data_string=This is a test" is not a valid option
at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.parseArgument(CmdLineParser.java:512)
at scraper.client.ScraperClient.main(ScraperClient.java:28)
... 5 more
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You say you're passing "-data_string", but the exception refers to "-profile_string"...?

Comment: I'm sory thats a typo in posted ques... i changed names for question

Comment: Does it work without the spaces?

Comment: yes it works without space perfectly. Actually i figured out. Need to use StringArrayOptionHandler handler and treat each word as separate string, save it in an array and then join on space.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.